# Why MAX is not working with where in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, where-clause

I am new to EF and writing this to select then max record that contains the combination. Now i want to pick `MAX` of those records only.

```
        public string GetMaxReportNo(string OfficeStationCombination = "")
        {
            InspectionReport InspectionReport= new InspectionReport();
            string VelosiReportNo="";

            var query = uow.InspectionReportRepository.GetQueryable().AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OfficeStationCombination))
            {
                VelosiReportNo = (string)query
                          .Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination))
                          .FirstOrDefault().VelosiReportNo.ToString();         
            }

            return VelosiReportNo;
        }
```

I tried everything to pick the max **InspectionReportID** record in `where` but nothing works

Comment: `Max` of what? Specify the column please.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Show the code that doesn't work properly and explain why it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @rad: inspectionReportID

Comment: @GertArnold: I want to pick the max ReportID from recrods on the basis of where clause in  (string)query
                          .Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination))
                          .FirstOrDefault().VelosiReportNo.ToString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Order** by the specified column (`inspectionReportID`) **descendingly** then take the **first** record:

```
VelosiReportNo = (string)query
                          .Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination))
                          .OrderByDesc(x => x.inspectionReportID)
                          .FirstOrDefault().VelosiReportNo.ToString();
```